# Passing Complex object via web sockets

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

Using .NetCore...

I have a C# server side code.

It creates an object list like:

```
[Serializable]
public class  MyObject
{
    public string test { get; set;}
}

var manyOfTheseObjects = new List<MyObject>();

manyOfTheseObjects   ~  add a few records
```

I now convert to a ByteArray ~

```
var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var mStream = new MemoryStream();
binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, manyOfTheseObjects);
socket.Send(mStream.ToArray());
```

On the JavaScript side I am listening on the web socket:

```
ws.onopen = function (data) {
try {
    console.log("onopen");
    console.log(JSON.parse(data).result);
    $("#divConnectionStatus").html("Client connected");
    resume= 1;}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    $("#divConnectionStatus").html("onopen: " + err);
}
```

};

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at WebSocket.Connect.ws.onopen (LiveFeed.js:182)
```

I am obviously doing this completely wrong...

NB

Changed this:

```
var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var mStream = new MemoryStream();
binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, manyOfTheseObjects);
socket.Send(mStream.ToArray());
```

to this:

```
socket.Send( JsonConvert.SerializeObject(manyOfTheseObjects ) );
```

Comment: A byte array is not necessarily valid JSON. You should probably use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` if you want JSON...

Comment: just changed it to that. same error. Will update my question with that code

Comment: Add what you get when you do `console.log(data)` within your `onopen` handler.

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is a .NET-specific binary serializer (and frankly: one I would avoid) - it isn't JSON. If you want: use a JSON serializer.

Comment: with the edit; what does the received payload turn out to be? As @HereticMonkey asks: what is `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: Note: `ws.onopen` is **not** the method that gets called when you receive messages

Comment: @MarcGravell it IS on the initial connection

Comment: @AndrewSimpson `Send` is **not** the initial connection... there is nothing interesting to be gleaned from `onopen` re `Send`. Source: I wrote the web-socket server here on Stack Overflow

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok.  my understanding that when u made the initial connection request the server can knowledge the request and respond which at that point i captured in the open event?  When i break-point it it does..?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson acknowledging and upgrading (101) the request is one thing - that's the `onopen`; however, sending a useful message is another; that is `onmessage`. The initial handshake doesn't transfer message data.

Comment: @MarcGravell obviously ur right. Which I am gad about as it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've switch to a JSON serializer: you want `onmessage`, not `onopen`:

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
try {
    console.log("onmessage");
    console.log(JSON.parse(evt.data).result);
    $("#divConnectionStatus").html("Message received");
    resume= 1;}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    $("#divConnectionStatus").html("onmessage: " + err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I will update my qquestion with the console.log(data); in a mo

Comment: When I initially request a connection credentials ae sent back from server to client. It is quite acceptable for me to catch the message there?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson no, because that isn't the event that gets raised for messages; `onmessage` is

Comment: I shall recheck. :)